# How to give user level access to private GitLab repository?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a private repository in **GitLab**. I have to give its access to members of my team. How can I do that using GitLab web-interface?

I know, how to do this in GitHub, but in GitLab it's somehow different.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

**Update 2021**: This answer is out of date, scroll down for the 2021 info.

**UPDATE:** Gitlab has changed a bit in 2 years, so here is the updated flow.

1. Click on the **project** that you want to share.
2. Click on the **Settings** tab (the gear icon on the left).
3. Click on the **Members** subtab.
4. Add member, and find the user if it exists on GitLab, or insert
   email to send an invitation.
5. Select access level for the user, the possible levels are:

- Guest, *can see wiki pages, view and create issues.*
- Reporter, *can do what the guest can plus view the code.*
- Developer, *normal developer access, can develop, but cannot push or merge to procted branches by default.*
- Maintainer, *can do everything except managing the project.*

5. For more info about the user access level refer to [gitlab official help](https://gitlab.com/help/user/permissions).
6. ***(Optional)*** Set expiration date of the user access.

---

**Old instructions:**

1. Click on the **project** that you want to share.
2. Click on **members**.
3. Add member, and find the user if it exists on GitLab, or insert
   email to send an invitation.

Comment: Actually you need to click **Settings** in between step 1 and 2.

Comment: If once there you don't have an option to add a user in the members pane, confirm that the member lock in the parent group, is unchecked. This will _"prevent adding new members to project membership within this group"_ https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/37494

Comment: There is no *Members* subtab in *Settings*.

Comment: As for October 2021, there's no *Member* subtab in the *Settings* :-(. I did that for another project just few weeks back and again, I cannot find where to set project members...

Comment: Found in *Project Information* --> *Members*

Comment: Today (2021-10-20) this answer is no longer correct, instead see the answer from @Maz341.

Comment: 1-3 steps on the page of the project on left nav panel: Project information -> Members

Answer (score 48):

## 2021 Updated Answer

1. Click on the project's name which you want to share.
2. On the left side, there is an option **Project Information** (hover on that).
3. Open **Members** and Project Members page will open.
4. Under invite member's Tab there is an option "GitLab member or Email
   address"
5. Enter the username/email of the person you want to add.
6. Choose a role from (Guest, Maintainer, Developer, Reporter)
7. Add Expiry date when you want to take back the role which you have
   assigned to this member. **(Optional)**
8. Click Invite.

---

**2020 Answer:**

1. Open Project (Click on project's name to open it)
2. On the left side bar the second last option is Members, open it.
3. Under invite member's Tab there is an option "GitLab member or Email
   address"
4. Enter the username/email of the person you want to add.
5. Choose a role from (Guest, Maintainer, Developer, Reporter)
6. Add Expiry date when you want to take back the role which you have
   assigned to this member. **(Optional)**
7. Click Invite.

---

**2019 Answer:**

1. Open Project (Click on project's name to open it)
2. On the left side bar the last option is Settings open it.
3. Click on members
4. Under **invite member's** Tab there is an option "GitLab member or Email address" Enter the username of the person you want to add.
5. Choose a role from (Guest, Maintainer, Developer, Reporter)
6. Add to project.

Comment: I just spent a solid 5 minutes with another dev on the phone being unable to add them to this project... thank you so much for the 2021 updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for the update. What if you have a message `The member's email address is not allowed for this project. Check with your administrator.` ?

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica For this go to Settings > General and verify that Restrict membership by email field contains the correct set of domains.

Answer (score 12):

**2021 - Answer**

1. Click on the project that you want to share.
2. Click on the Project Information tab. (first icon)
3. Click on the Members subtab.

Comment: Finally... Why are they changing this over and over again???

Comment: There isn't any tab currently labelled "Project Information". You have to go to your project and the "Members" option is on the left... at least until 2022 when they'll probably change it again.

Answer (score 9):

The prior answer has a problem.  The (poor) Gitlab UI does not have a "members" option to click on after clicking on the project.

You first must click on the gear icon at the upper right to reveal the members option.

Comment: You are correct. The gitlab gui was updated so you must now click settings before members.

Answer (score 4):

## 2022 July - Answer

Click on the following:

1. **Project**
2. **Settings** (left panel)
3. **General** (default selection, just make sure to stay in this tab)
4. Expand the **visibility, project features, permissions** section
5. Set the **project visibility** drop-down to Private and a link to **project members** will appear
6. Click the link. It will take you to: https://gitlab.com/<namespace/repo_name>/-/project_members

[Screenshot showing steps on the GitLab page... (not enough reputation yet to embed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcVrF.png)

Answer (score 3):

Simply visit URL

```
https://gitlab.com/<repo-path>/-/project_members
```

And modify the user's permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Nov 2021 This is now located under the Group Information section.
Select members
Invite those who you want to collaborate with

[image: Group Information menu]

Answer (score 0):

**2024 Answer**

Under your Project Panel on the left hand side.
Select **Manage**
This will give you a pop up - with three options.
Select Members
Select the Blue Button labled "Invite Members" from the top right hand side.
Enter the members (username or name or email address)
Select Role (Guest, Reporter, Developer, Maintainer or Owner)

- under the role before assigning *
  Select Expiration date (good if you hire a contractor or temp worker) it is optional.
  Select the Blue "Invite" button when you are done.