# You are not allowed to push code to this project

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have created a project and cloned it in my local machine. I have done a change and I have committed it without problems. Now I am trying to push those changes from local to the remote repository in Gitlab

I got this error message: -

[image]

How I can fix the issue

Comment: Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31908222/how-to-give-user-level-access-to-private-gitlab-repository)

Answer (score 1):

Please check the settings of that repository you are trying to push. and make sure you have the proper read/write access for that repository.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are trying to use HTTPS push method, and think you could try SSH [https://youtu.be/0z28J0RfaJM] method to do push since HTTPS method is often blocked,
check if project permissions are not causing this error as suggested by ***Saikat Roy***.
Check if your user is a member and if not try to add yourself as a project member. From the project page click the settings gear and then click members. Add yourself as a member to the project if you can if not ask admin to do it.

Also You should be aware that if you do this,
`https://youruser:password@gitlab.com/bla`
your gitlab password will be stored in plaintext in your `.git` directory, which is obviously undesirable.